# How to build table with for and if conditions in following way

Tags: html, django

I have table  :

```
 <table >
   <tr><th>Years</th>{% for year in years %}<td>{{ year }}</td>
   {% endfor %}</tr>
   <tr><th>Score</th>{% for a in ab  %}{% if a > 203 %}<td class="green"> 
   {{a}}</td>{% elif  a < 20 %} 
   <td class="orange">{{a}}</td>{% else %}<td class="red"> {{a}}
   </td>{% endif %}{% endfor %}</tr>

   <tr><th>Score2</th>{% for b in bc %}{% if  b == "STRONG" %}
   <td class="green">{{b}} {% elif  b ==  "STABLE"  %}
   <td class="orange">{{b}}</td> {% else %} <td class="red"> {{b}}
   </td>{% endif %}{% endfor %}</tr>
```

but it shows horizontal rows like this :

```
Years   2015   2014   2013
Score    20     30     56
Score2   weak   weak   stable
```

whereas i want to turn them vertical like this :

```
   Years   Score     Score2

    2015    20        weak
    2014    30        weak
    2013    56        stable
```

I shows my css coloration as this is smth gives me challenge to convert the table vertical.

Woudld highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your context into the format below and pass to the template for rendering.

```
context = {
    'data':[
        [2015, 20, 'weak'], 
        [2014, 30, 'weak'], 
        [2013, 56, 'stable']
    ]
}
```

In HTML Template, the value inside each `element` is accessed by using `element.index` . I only give if-else condition for the second row, but you may get the point.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Years</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Score2</th>   
    </tr>
    {% for element in data %}
    <tr>    
        <td>{{element.0}}</td>
        <td class="{% if element.1 > 203 %}green{% elif element.1 < 20 %}orange{% else %}red{% endif %}" >{{element.1}}</td>
        <td>{{element.2}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code to something like this:

```
<table >
<head><th>Years</th><th>Score</th><th>Score2</th></head>
<body>
# This is just sample for how to align items...add the if else accordingly
{% for a in mydata %}
<tr>
<td>{{a.0}}</td>
<td>{{a.1}}</td>
<td>{{a.2}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</table>
```

Change the context in your view function like this:

```
mydata = [(years, score1, score2), ]
```